# How to make carousel transition automatically?

Tags: javascript

I have the following html, css and script and would like the carousel to switch between the 3 slides automatically as well as give users the option to jump around using the dots. What am I missing?

Live here – https://www.assemblyresearch.co.uk/

Thanks!

```
<script>
  var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}

</script>
```

Comment: First of all, you're missing a working fiddle demo ;>

Comment: Also it would be helpful to know what happens right now and what do you expect to happen

Comment: Sorry – will update. It's currently live here https://www.assemblyresearch.co.uk/

Comment: You can add a setInterval.

Comment: @gg_ thanks – would you mind showing me how/where? I am new to this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you try something like this:

```
<script>
  var slideIndex = 1;
  setInterval(function(){
    showSlides(slideIndex);
    slideIndex++;
  }, 1000);
...
</script>
```

This just adds a `setInterval()` function that iterates every second that just calls the showSlides function and increases the index by one. If you are not familiar with the setInterval function you can think it as a timer that ticks every `X` milliseconds where `X` is the number at the end of the function. This one for example ticks every second.

### EDIT

I also suggest you think how to manage when the counter goes higher than your maximum slide number. I would just do a simple math function like so: `slideIndex = (slideIndex + 1) % slides.lenght`. The problem is that you do not have the object `slides` at that scope so you should bring it out of the `showSlides` function.